# Characters not recognized while reading from file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding, ifstream

I have the following c++ code in visual studio to read characters from a file.

```
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);

    if (infile.fail()) {
        cout << "Error reading from file: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        cout << argv[0] << endl;
    }
    else {
        char currentChar;

        while (infile.get(currentChar)) {
            cout << currentChar << " " << int(currentChar) << endl;
            //... do something with currentChar
        }

        ofstream outfile("output.txt");
        outfile << /* output some text based on currentChar */;
    }
    infile.close();
```

The file in this case is expected to contain mostly normal ASCII characters, with the exception of two: `“` and `”`.

The problem is that the code in it's current form is not able to recognise those characters. `cout`ing the character outputs garbage, and its int conversion yields a negative number that's different depending on where in the file it occurs.

I have a hunch that the problem is encoding, so I've tried to imbue `infile` based on some examples on the internet, but I haven't seemed to get it right. `infile.get` either fails when reaching the quote character, or the problem remains. What details am I missing?

Comment: Try `(int)(unsigned char)currentChar`. For conversion from `char` to `int`, sign extension happens if `char` is signed by default (what seems obviously be the case for your compiler) which is in this case undesired. The intermediate conversion over `unsigned char` can prevent this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `int currentChar;` and [`std::istream::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) which would return valid characters in the range of [1, 255]. Read failure would be signalled by return < 0, in this case.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?  Exactly what bytes are in the file?

Comment: @MartinBonner according to the file command, of the input files I have, one is `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`, and the other  `UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators`. The characters supported are all ascii characters, and `“` and `”`

Comment: In addition to @MartinBonner - Typographic quotes are not part of [ISO 8815-1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) nor [ISO 8859-15](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-15). (I suspected from your name that these could be used.) Hence, you probably use [UTF-8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). In UTF-8, typographic quotes are stored with three bytes.

Comment: [UTF-8 encoding](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl): LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK: U+2018 as UTF-8: `"\xe2\x80\x9c"`. The others have values close to this.

Comment: "The characters supported are all ascii characters, and `“` and `”`". ASCII (from 0 ... 127) is a real subset of UTF-8. (This is how UTF-8 was defined by intention.) So, your file is probably encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Scheff.  Typographic quotes are not part of ISO 8815-1 or ISO 8859-15, but they *are* part of Windows 1252.  We *really* need to see the actual octets of the data.  OP: If you have `file`, I presume you have Posix tools available.  What does `od -t x1z` say? (single byte hex, with character display).  I'm really interested in one of the typographic quotes.

Comment: @MartinBonner "Typographic quotes are not part of ISO 8815-1 or ISO 8859-15, but they are part of Windows 1252." Damn. Not carefully enough researched... In (my) perfect world, there were only UTF and Unicode. All the other encodings are old and annoying.

Comment: @MartinBonner for the file content `“cos341asdas”`, `od -t x1z` generates:
`0000000 e2 80 9c 63 6f 73 33 34 31 61 73 64 61 73 e2 80  >...cos341asdas..<
0000020 9d                                               >.<
0000021`

Comment: The `file` program guesses the character encoding. It could always guess a many but it always guesses just one. You shouldn't have to guess. You should know. If users are providing the text files, you just have to tell them is use a certain encoding or require them to tell you the encoding they are using. BTW—ASCII is used every day in certain contexts but it is not at all "normal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are trying to read is likely UTF-8 encoded. The reason most characters read fine is because UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII.

In order to read a UTF-8 file I'll refer you to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
...

// Write file in UTF-8
std::wofstream wof;
wof.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,0x10ffff,std::generate_header>));
wof.open(L"file.txt");
wof << L"This is a test.";
wof << L"This is another test.";
wof << L"\nThis is the final test.\n";
wof.close();

// Read file in UTF-8
std::wifstream wif(L"file.txt");
wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));

std::wstringstream wss;
wss << wif.rdbuf();
```

(from [here](https://sockbandit.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/c-read-and-write-utf-8-file-using-standard-libarary/))

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It's worth noting that wcout doesn't follow this fix. [source](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/126557/#msg685276)

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
 while (infile.get(&currentChar, 1))
```

Also, be sure that you pass `argv[1]`. Print its value:

```
cout<<argv[1]<<endl;
```

Comment: This too just changes which overload of `get` is called.  It doesn't change the OP's problem which is how to read non-ASCII.