# C - Cannot read all characters when reading a file

Tags: c++, file, encoding, file-io, ifstream

I am currently working on a lossless compression algorithm using the Huffman technique.
I managed to compress the desired file, and save the compressed data to a file.
However, I am unable to correctly read what is recorded in this file. Preferably, I would like to store the contents of this file in a `std::string`.

Here is the content of this file:

```
00000L,1LP10LURD100LVRj1LLRQRER.Rm1LlRr1LiRe1000LpRdRn100Lv100LC1LARF1LIRNRbRcRa100Lo100Lh1Lx1LMRSRf1LgRqRs1LuRt

X6*ÃWØ¿¸u÷üwµS™’ð‚<)âóUO_mÁ9Õö/ë‰ÍÌ Ï-,SÁúÚâuçëðÒì`WVwÿƒüšÎë‰Š?Âgÿ­PÞuâ[CßTø¸CJŸy™“Þ¸Ý{+1sü <Ï~÷øà·\@¾¯àç¦¡ú±Õö/Þüºû"í+ª•tÊæ+Ã“¸Ð÷Õ>.'¦º¾Åü
úá‡
lÀ•¥¸Äq/?03òØ2'>÷?>9»ŸtY®Ùyù„‰u®'^~¿Û‚sŸ–Ã¶Ž(wß°/ì–~+K*•O´ ÿV:âyšö¨oãúü:ÿhrkã[‹7çjëÄ¶†KßW›˜iSêj£ÓúÆÉ×ûoÆÉï\l ÜKª‘ÚÉ¬®b]T«ÏÖ42+4­Ô2µ“í«Ç7•’Ðä×Æ·ØÃ·+ìÊþ¸˜¡sü!xSC—7ëoÿø=_bÿÔÕG§ÃIöÕÐÊV¥:ÅÅ?]Yß„ËsòÖx×™øÞíàæÍÓ+˜¯~7Æ´ 
puQäöÕA}ÿ².Õ {vÓ+˜¯¾ÍÌ ŽÞ¹úb+
 ç·ñd³óÿSUŸ
/ˆ®Œ|/õ}‹ñT`»áúüi|EuÄæçMSs’âóUOrßUSí
 ïFòH{Tû8ð¹C«ì_×¯?_†—ÄWÅæªöV’ŽÜc`>ö0Á‹þÚ8¡ß~ÃH;ÜÙ¸dY¿;þ8-\`ÈœûÜüÞþSS™Zäî#d÷®7Bûo}åÊª¿ŽŽ(wß°Òö?õø0¡¿¾¯àÕ×‰hñÇ7·™­Û‚rþ[ª%«KÅ’ý_býCxBíëŸ¿‡
löàœ„õÄææ÷îªÃÜ0ëðaxSˆ¬C´êÿm¨³]¯À¦W1^§T_XË®â6OF÷l4Ž;¦¿æ{÷»y—úØ«äý°sºâ³JÝB7Æ¶…öñ«&ksóâóUOB    ‘9÷¹ùÅf•º†ë^¹,«Ì÷ïCIÏÖ0Áÿ¯Á¿žšçå£‚{é„Eë"í¡–VK{åSÈ-Êjs"+
*}œx_“Þ¸Þ[·[ŸjÃBµN[êª}¡}’ÏÖ4<…^+PÞ‡16kø¼Õ^‡&ÁÓO.UUülñªY/dÅÏð€þ7O·?X×.„4Ÿm]2¹Š÷’œO©ªOúš¨ôøiSìãÂülžõÆòØ½ºÜûPÞªrßUSí?Õ~lÜ­@_ÿ­%›ŠÃIÏÖ,ïèÁwÂü4©¯ö¨oéZÁœSøªÿA¸—XõÂòO$Ìþ¸Äq>Ú¹¿[ÞY¬‹µòÑÄrÄÙ¯r†…öáæl ™Ÿ{Ÿ›&²¹Œº‹þÙÄíæ_ëBõb}çÃb8"ZW^Òº©VÉ¬®bp¨±í¿Ê¥Sí³¯pÈ³~vÎü ï–çç\LP¹þÛBûpÆó7\LP¹þ‚<)dÖW1d¾ëì‹¶‹5Ûo3
```

Here is the code I wrote to read its contents:

```
int main(){     
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;
    
    std::ifstream myfile("my_file.txt.huff");
    while (std::getline(myfile, line)){
        ++number_of_lines;;
        std::cout << "line number: " << number_of_lines << " content: " << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I also tried via this way:

```
int main(){     
    FILE *find = fopen("my_file.txt.huff", "r");
    int ca;
    while(EOF != (ca=fgetc(find)))
          std::cout << (char)ca;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the console rendering for the first code given:

```
line number : 1 content : 00000L,1LP10LURD100LVRj1LLRQRER.Rm1LlRr1LiRe1000LpRdRn100Lv100LC1LARF1LIRNRbRcRa100Lo100Lh1Lx1LMRSRf1LgRqRs1LuRt
line number : 2 content :
line number : 3 content : X6*├WÏ┐©Øu¸³wÁSÖÆ­é<)Ô¾UO_m┴9ı÷/Ùë═╠ ¤-,S┴·┌ÔuþÙ­Êý`WVw â³
```

At every time I try to read this file the problem is repeated. Indeed, the methods I use do not allow me to read it entirely.

Why does this problem occur?

thank you in advance

N.B: I was able to test, without success, the solution provided by Cillié Malan in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48988288/9036238) post. I'm having trouble for converting from a `std::wstringstream` to a `std::string` correctly.

Comment: It's binary data, you shouldn't be using text functions like `getline()`.

Comment: You need to open in `ios::binary` mode and I would recommend `std::vector<uint8_t>` or some other unsigned type. There is no guarantee binary bytes are in the range of ASCII chars. See [std::ios_base::openmode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) Binary files have no concept of "lines". Your use of reading with `fgetc()` is correct, but you cannot simply print the content to `stdout`, you will need to store the values as an `unsigned` byte.

Comment: Indeed I did not understand at all why it did not work! I just understood my mistake, it is much clearer now. It was not a simple text file.
Some people have developed the solution you are developping here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138353/how-to-read-a-binary-file-into-a-vector-of-unsigned-chars

Thanks for taking the time to look into my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short example that opens the file in binary mode and reads the entire file into a `std::vector<uint8_t>`. (you can also use a `std::array<uint8_t>` if you like). You open the file, `.seekg()` to the end, get the number of bytes and create the vector with that number of bytes and then `.read()` the file into the vector.

The following takes the filename as the first argument and outputs the content in hex format (for large files, change the output before testing to limit what is dumped to `stdout`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate filename given as argument */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient arguments\n"
                    "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename.bin\n";
        return 1;
    }
    /* open file in binary mode, position at-the-end */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1], std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!f.is_open())                           /* validate file open for reading */
        return 1;
    
    size_t nbytes = f.tellg();                  /* get number of bytes in file */
    f.seekg (0);                                /* rewind */
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> arr(nbytes);           /* declare vector with adequate storage */

    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&arr[0]), nbytes);   /* read file into vector */ 
    
    if (f.bad() || f.fail())                    /* validate read */
        return 1;

    for (auto& i : arr) /* output results (limit for larger files) */
        std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << static_cast<uint32_t>(i) << " ";
    std::cout.put ('\n');
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There are several ways to approach this.

Comment: +1 clear and well explain. You could elaborate on some points: why use unsigned type for storing binary data, how ifstream::f.tellg works and why the start at end was necessary. Is there an solution that does not require reinterpret cast?

Comment: Not a "fancy", but you can use a plain-old C-style cast `f.read((char*)&arr[0], nbytes);` A cast is necessary to satisfy [std::basic_istream::read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) which provides the declaration for `basic_istream& read( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );` taking `char_type *s`.

Comment: You explain really well. I would not have thought of going on this path. I'm not used to using the static_cast <>() and reinterpret_cast<>() functions, but this is the time to start. I will inquire :) Thank you very much, this is clear for me